Intel RealSense D455 is not working with ROS noetic in Jetson Orin Nano
I tried connecting the Realsense D455 camera, to get point cloud information from the camera. Works fine on a PC. But when connected to Jetson Orin Nano, its shows up with the SDK and Realsense viewer application. But doesn't work when this command is used
$ roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch filters:=pointcloud 
How do I get pointcloud data to be published if the command is not working?

When you say it doesn't work, is there anything in the log files? Also, this seems to be the same as this question: Intel real sense d455 is not working with ROS1 (Hardware Jetson Orin Nano)

You can set enable_pointcloud:=true to get pointcloud data.
